# jQuery / CSS: proper way to hide a column

Tags: jquery, html, css, show-hide

I am pretty new to jQuery and CSS and hope someone can help me with the following:

I have a standard HTML table with a colgroup, thead, tbody and several tr's and td's in the body and would like to use a CSS class to hide certain columns.

**My CSS class looks like this:**

```
.hideAll
{
    display:none;
}
```

What is the best / correct way to apply this class ? To the col's in the colgroup, to the th's in the thead, to the tr's or td's in the tbody or to several of them at the same time ?

**My table looks something like this:**

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
       <col />
       <col />
       <col />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you know which exactly column you want to hide. Give it a class name.

```
<table>
<colgroup>
   <col />
   <col />
   <col />
</colgroup>
<thead>
    <tr><th class="target">AAA</th><th>BBB</th><th>CCC</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td class="target">111</td><td>111</td><td>111</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="target">222</td><td>222</td><td>222</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="target">333</td><td>333</td><td>333</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Then you can use jquery [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method to add your hideAll class to them.

```
$('.target').addClass('hideAll');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jm7B6/)

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, if you want to remove the class use what @andrea.spot suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Like @drip already told you, it would be usefull adding some class name to your table's children.

Anyway you can set the given class to your elements like this:

```
$('myElementSelector').addClass('hideAll');
```

and then if you want to remove the class, the code will be:

```
$('myElementSelector').removeClass('hideAll');
```

For jQuery selector, I suggest you to read [jQuery selectors' documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

But if you are new to jQuery world and in the future you won't need it so much, you can consider learning [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/), which elevates you from pure dom management.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply - this helped a lot !

Comment: Great answer man! I think i'll take a look at that KnockoutJS ;)

Comment: Nice to you ear that from both of you.. See ya!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much you can just stack them and add the class.

```
$('col,tr,th,td').addClass('hideAll')
```

But it really depends which one exactly you want to hide.

If this is just for "try" than this is good. But if have a large project you might consider adding some kind of class to the table and targeting it instead all of the elements trough out the page.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/L4TEq/

I made a simple script which allows you to hide an entire column just giving to a column `class="hidden"`.

This might help and semplify your work.

It's based on elements [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/). In this way, you can hide all corresponding ths and tds with the same index of the column.